# По нажатию кнопки изменять размер div

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем привет. Есть такой вопрос имею блок `div` и в ней `button`. Пытаюсь изменить размеры `div` по нажатию кнопки. Делаю так:

```js
$(".mainbtn").on('click', function(event) {
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass(".a.selected");
});
```

```css
.div-a {
  height: 250px;
  width: 110px;
  .div-a.selected {
    filter: grayscale(0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="div-a">
    <button class="mainbtn">hi</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-a">
    <button class="mainbtn">hi</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-a">
    <button class="mainbtn">hi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему не работает?

Comment: добавьте сам html елемент в вопрос, и исправте ошибки синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 ошибки

1. `"event.currentTarget"` `->` `event.currentTarget.parentNode` (Вы передали строку, а необходимо - ссылку на элемент, на родителя, а не на текущий элемент)
2. `".a.selected"` `->` `"a selected"` (https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$(".mainbtn").on('click', function(event) {
  $(event.currentTarget.parentNode).toggleClass("a selected");
});
```

```css
.a.selected{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 13px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100px;
  border:solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="mainbtn">mainbtn</button>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня div блок class записан через parent-div. Как я понимаю так не правильно будет: event.currentTarget.parent-divNode. Как правильно?

Comment: @Александр добавьте разметку в вопрос

Comment: @Александр не важно какой там класс, если это элемент-предок обратиться к нему можно так, как я написал

Comment: обновил, не понимаю, что за node

Comment: @Александр https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Comment: так я понял, я подредактировал код, но почему-то у меня некорректно работает

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы не привели `html-разметку`, но предположу, что `.mainbtn` - это класс у `div`.
2. Передавая в `$()` `"event.currentTarget"` вы передаёте строку, а не ссылку на `currentTarget`. Правильно `$(event.currentTarget)`
3. Так не обращаются (`.a.selected`) - правильно `a selected`.
4. Старайтесь использовать один стиль. Если вы начали использовать `"` или `'`, то не мешайте их.

```js
$(".item").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bgc-grey {
  background: grey;
}

.selected {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item bgc-grey"></div>
<div class="item bgc-grey"></div>
<div class="item bgc-grey"></div>
```

Второй вариант:

Комментарий: Переменная `$rect` имеет название с префиксом `$`, что говорит(подсказывает) о том, что там `jquery-объект`. Такое именование переменной считается хорошим тоном (на мой взгляд) и позволяет сразу понять что там находится.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  const $rect = $("#rect");
  $rect.hasClass("selected") ? $rect.removeClass("selected") : $rect.addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bgc-grey {
  background: grey;
}

.selected {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Press</button>
<div id="rect" class="bgc-grey"></div>
```

Третий вариант:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  const $rect = $(this).parent();
  $rect.hasClass("selected") ? $rect.removeClass("selected") : $rect.addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bgc-grey {
  background: grey;
}

.selected {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect" class="bgc-grey">
  <button>Press</button>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, за ошибки, но главный вопросы, при нажатии на кнопку, чтобы менялся другой элемент(div)

Comment: Какой именно? Приведите в вопросе

Comment: то есть при нажатии кнопки менялся размер div, а не button